# Cannot access shared folders from Windows

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing

I've taken the plunge and installed ubuntu to hoping to be able to set up a server for sharing music files and running torrents. .

I have also installed Samba, and although I can see the files from my windows 10 laptop I cannot access the shared files.

Testparm look like this

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[Torrents]"
Processing section "[Down]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    syslog = 0
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[Down]
    comment = Torrent folder
    create mask = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0666
    force directory mode = 0777
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /media/peter/Torrents/down
    read only = No
```

The error on the windows says

"Windows cannot access". Have tried with both name and address, but get the same error message either way.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run or copy the files from the share?

Comment: The share will be for storage - so copying files to and from the share

Comment: Does the user 'nobody ' (=default value for guest account) exist in you password file?

Comment: The passwd file contains - nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a samba issue. It is a Linux permissions issue.

> path = /media/peter/Torrents/down

Linux creates the /media/peter directory in such a way that it limits who can traverse it to peter and no one else. The guest user is not peter so it never gets to the /Torrents/down part of the path. One solution is to make the guest user appear to be you for that share by adding a `force user = peter` to the share definition:

`[Down]
    comment = Torrent folder
    create mask = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0666
    force directory mode = 0777
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /media/peter/Torrents/down
    force user = peter
    read only = No`

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`